# No rule to make target with Cmake protobuf

Tags: cmake, protobuf-c

I am trying to get Cmake to compile my protofiles. I use the following CMakeLists.txt for that.

```
include(FindProtobuf)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
# check if protobuf was found
if(PROTOBUF_FOUND)
    message ("protobuf found")
else()
    message (FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find Protobuf")
endif()

include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(PROTO_FILES
    msg.proto)

PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRC PROTO_HEADER ${PROTO_FILES})

message ("PROTO_SRC = ${PROTO_SRC}")
message ("PROTO_HEADER = ${PROTO_HEADER}")

add_library(proto ${PROTO_HEADER} ${PROTO_SRC})
```

My folder structure:

```
cpp/
  protos
    msg.proto
    CMakeLists.txt
  build
    debug
```

I build from build/debug. Protobuf is found. For Proto_src and Proto_header I find:

```
PROTO_SRC = /home/mike/code/protos/cpp/build/debug/protos/msg.pb.cc
PROTO_HEADER = /home/mike/code/protos/cpp/build/debug/protos/msg.pb.h
```

but then when trying to compile I get the following error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '../../protos/msg.proto', needed by 'protos/msg.pb.h'.  Stop.
```

I got the setup from https://github.com/shaochuan/cmake-protobuf-example

I don't see what I am missing here?

Comment: According to `make` output, there is no `msg.proto` file under `protos/` subdirectory. Are you sure that you have this file? Note, in the example the file is named `message.proto`. Don't you forgot to rename it?

Comment: it had the same name, but was in a subdirectory msgs. Silly error. Thanks for the hint.